# Robotium: searchText

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I have a strange situation I can't explain myself.
The following code works well:

`solo.sleep(1000);

assertTrue(solo.searchText("Banking"));`

but the following code fails:

`assertTrue(solo.waitForText("Banking", 1, 1000));`

Can someone can explain me this?

Kind regards,
Alban.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that '1000' in waitForText isn't setting a delay, it's setting how long to keep looking. If it doesn't find the text within that time, it returns false. [See Robotium source](http://github.com/jayway/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/RobotiumUtils.java#L148)

Try the second version like this and see if it doesn't work:

```
assertTrue(solo.waitForText("Banking", 1, 10000)); // Take up to 10 seconds
```

Also, the delay before the first one probably doesn't change anything. I think the first example would work just as well if it was only:

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Banking"));
```

Comment: So... did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Before robotium-1.7.1 there were some issues with searchText(). It was definetely not always finding the text even when it should. You might want to try again with simple code without timing.